# Get LastLogonUser and LastLogonDate on computers in AD

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap

We can use

```
Get-ADComputer $computerName -Properties LastLogonDate
```

to get `LastLogonDate`. But how to know which user did the Last Logon? `Get-ADUser` has a `LastLogon` property, but it seems we could not use it to decide which computer the user logon.

Answer (score 0):

You're misunderstanding the meaning of `LastLogonDate` in this context. It's the timestamp of when the computer account last authenticated against the domain, not the timestamp of when a user last logged into that particular computer.

To determine which user last logged into a specific computer you need to have logon event auditing enabled on that machine and extract the information from the Security eventlog (see [here](http://www.planetcobalt.net/sdb/lastlogon.shtml)):

```
$computer = '...'

Get-EventLog Security -Computer $computer -InstanceId 4624 -EntryType SuccessAudit |
    Where-Object {
        $_.Message -match 'logon type:\s+(2|10)\s' -and
        $_.Message -match 'new logon:[\s\S]*?account name:\s+(.*?)\s'
    } |
    Sort-Object TimeGenerated -Desc |
    Select-Object -First 1 TimeGenerated, @{n='Account';e={$matches[1]}}
```

To limit the amount of data that is retrieved from the remote host I'd suggest to run `Get-EventLog` with a starting date (`-After`). Processing the entire Security eventlog could take a lot of time otherwise.