# Find the last time a server was logged in to

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find the last time a virtual workstation was logged in to. We have an OU filled with virtual workstations and I am trying to see if there being used. If I can find a way to do it with a `foreach` command that will pull either a list of virtual workstation from a text doc or a way to target a specific OU and it feeds back the last time each of those VMs was logged into that would be great.

I have tried:

```
query user /server:$SERVER`
```

which will show me the last login and date and user which is perfect, but I had to be logged in to the machine to run it, I just need to get it for all these VMs.

I have also tried:

```
Get-ADComputer -Identity computername -Properties * | ft name, lastlogondate
```

This works well and shows me last login just not sure how to do it from a list of machines or target an OU.

Comment: The lastlogondate of an AD computerobject is not the date a user last logged on to that computer. It is the last date the computer logged on to the domain. If a computer just starts without somebody logging in to it, it will log in to the domain.

Comment: The value of `LastLogonDate` only incidentally matches what you're looking for, because the time the VM was started coincides with the time the user logged in. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199237/1630171).

Answer (score 0):

To limit the search to a specific OU, you need the additional parameter -SearchBase:

```
Get-ADComputer -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=IT,OU=FrontOffice,OU=Windows10,OU=MigratedComputers,OU=XXX,DC=XXXX,DC=XXX'
```