# Can I parse Date using -Filter parameter in the ActiveDirectory Powershell module?

Tags: string, powershell, parsing, active-directory

I would like to return all machines where the LastLogonDate attribute exceeds 180 days. I would like to approach this using the -filter parameter. Currently, I tried

```
$lastLogonRestriction = (Get-date).AddDays(-180)

Get-ADComputer -Filter "LastLogonDate -lt $lastLogonRestriction" -Properties * | Select LastLogonDate, Name
```

But I get an error stating it can't parse it

```
Get-ADComputer : Error parsing query: 'LastLogonDate -lt 08/22/2021 12:02:23' Error Message: 'Operator Not supported: ' at position: '21'.
At C:\Users\Admin.MH\Desktop\powershell\AD\moveDisabledComputers.ps1:8 char:1
+ Get-ADComputer -Filter "LastLogonDate -lt $lastLogonRestriction" -Pro
```

Sure, I can pipe my output into a where-object and search for this but this -filter param would be better

Comment: No need to return all the properties just to grab 2. Just query for the `LastLogonDate` property, seeing as `name` is already one of the properties returned.

Answer (score 1):

You probably just need a single quote around the variable:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter "LastLogonDate -lt '$lastLogonRestriction'" -Properties * | Select LastLogonDate, Name
```

But keep in mind that a computer's last logon date is the last time the computer authenticated to the domain, not the last time someone logged into the computer. If you're looking for the last time someone logged into the computer, read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25199237/1202807).

Comment: This absolutely worked and is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This value is stored in a weird format. It resembles unix epoch time, but isn't quite the same. See here:

> https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12814.active-directory-lastlogontimestamp-conversion.aspx

Comment: I think you're referring to `LastLogonTimestamp` and the format it takes is from `.ToFileTime()`